# Get customer info from database after selecting dropdown using php/ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

i'm trying to make a simple webpage for making invoices. to select/load customer info i'm using a [select](/questions/tagged/select) dropdown filled with all the customers in the database. 
after selecting a customer i want php to get all the values of that customer from the database and echo somewhere else on the page. 
thought it would be something simple but tried everything and cant seem to get it to work.

any help?

after deleting all the code that didn't work anyway this is what i'm left with:

```
<select name="selectCustomer">
    <option selected>Klantnaam</option>
    <?
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$c_tbl_name);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo    '<option value="'.$row['c_id'].'">';
            echo        $row['c_name'];
            echo    '</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Have you got PHP `short_open_tag` enabled? http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: i'm getting no errors. i'm just not able to work out how to do it. cant find any examples and cant even get to the point where i'm getting errors

Comment: Ah - as I understand the question, I think you've not quite 'got' PHP or AJAX... PHP is entirely server-side, you can't update what's displayed on the client based on a user-interaction happening on the client (selecting something from the dropdown) without either posting the form to the server or utilising JavaScript and/or AJAX in some way. AJAX is simply a way for JavaScript to load data in from an URL - the URL would be a dynamic PHP page to which you'd pass the variables (e.g. the `c_id` from your `<select>`) and it's the JS that updates the client based on that response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some small AJAX function to do that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('[name="selectCustomer"]').change(function(){
        $('#result').load('load_data_from_db.php', {
            customer : $(this).val();
        });
    });
});
```

You than need a script `load_data_from_db.php` which takes the selected customer, generates the content and returns it to the client where it would be placed into an element with the ID result.

Comment: that is the script i am looking for. im probably a noob for asking this, but how do i use the values i got from the db. a simple echo inside `load_data_from_db.php` doesn't seem to work. what should the file roughly look like?

Comment: A simple `echo` should be just fine. It would than be placed into the DIV with the ID #result (so this DIV has to be on the page).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$c_tbl_name) or die(mysql_error());
```

and this will give info if the query failed.

Furthermore, you should really consider upgrading from mysql() as it is now deprecated. Try google search for 'php PDO'.

Comment: thanks for the PDO tip.. ill have a good look at that. regarding my problem.. the dropdown works perfect, gets filled with all existing customers in db with the correct id in value. now when i select one of those customers i want to echo all the customers info somewere else on the page

Comment: Instead of PDO (which is good to use), you can also use MySQLi (MySQL improved) which is very similar to the MySQL extension. You can even use it in procedual style. But I would also recommend to use it in object oriented style or switch to PDO.